# Javascript function doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to delete all checked elements with javascript,but it doesn't work,any suggestions?
This is my code

```
<script>
function deleteR(){

$('input[name=actionck]:checked').each(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'demo10_helper.jsp',
        data: "command=delete&recordID=$id",
        dataType: "xml",
        cache: false,
        success: function(xml) {
            window.location.reload(true);
            $("#recordgrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Failed to connect to API.");
        }
     });


});
}

</script>
```

this is how i call it :

```
  <button type="button" onClick="deleteR()">
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing in console. I think the js function is working but you are looking for events triggered on check.Put a console.log or an alert just after function deleteR(){ and check if that is getting called

Comment: change [dataType: "json"] then Try it

Comment: @LinusKleen +1 ,but am still getting an internal server error

Comment: This seems very inefficient. It will make one request for each checked input. Wouldn't it be better to collect all the checked input id's and send one request?

Comment: how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line of your code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'demo10_helper.jsp',
    data: "command=delete&recordID=$id", // <--- this line
    dataType: "xml",
    // ...
});
```

it looks as though you'd like to interpolate the local variable `id` into the string. Javascript does not know interpolation; what you want is *concatenation*:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'demo10_helper.jsp',
    data: "command=delete&recordID=" + id, // <--- concatenation
    dataType: "xml",
    // ...
});
```

Comment: works greatly,thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
data: "command=delete&recordID=$id",
```

you are sending "$id" as part of the string literal. Perhaps you mean:

```
data: "command=delete&recordID=" + id,
```

Also:

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");
```

would be much more efficient as:

```
var id = this.id;
```

and a lot less to type. :-)